# How to split generator data into train and test without converting to dense data?

Tags: tensorflow, scipy, scikit-learn

I want to split generator data into train and test without converting to dense data to reduce RAM consumption.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Data set
ds = np.array([
    ('Alice', 0),
    ('Bob', 1),
    ('Charlie', 1),
])
x = ds[:, 0]
y = ds[:, 1]

# Change texts into numeric vectors
max_sequence = max(x, key=len)
vocab_processor = tf.contrib.learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor(len(max_sequence))
text_processed = vocab_processor.fit_transform(x)
print(type(text_processed)) # <class 'generator'>

# Split into training and test
x_train, \
x_test, \
y_train, \
y_test = train_test_split(text_processed, y)
```

However `train_test_split` complains:

```
TypeError: Singleton array array(<generator object VocabularyProcessor.transform at 0x116f6f830>, dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection`
```

### Questions

- How can I split text_processed as is sparse data?
- Is it worth trying [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) instead of `VocabularyProcessor`?

### Context

Assume I'm trying [this spam/ham tutorial](https://github.com/nfmcclure/tensorflow_cookbook/blob/18db04690947977d7a0102385a9bda0593f4902f/09_Recurrent_Neural_Networks/02_Implementing_RNN_for_Spam_Prediction/02_implementing_rnn.py#L74-L92) with much larger number of data and longer text.

Comment: I don't know about `tensorflow`, but `numpy` arrays are always built from a full list, or with `fromiter` from an iterable.  `fromiter` requires that you specify dtype and returns a 1d.  `np.array(<generator>)` produces a 1 element object array, containing the unevaluated generator.

Comment: The error from the `train_test_split` says that the data provided to it is not an array. `train_test_split` handles sparse arrays perfectly. But it cant handle a generator. You need to iterate the generate the produce the array and then pass it onto `train_test_split`.

Comment: There is something in TF called [ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator). For what I understand it's a generator but that has a parameter `validation_split`. I believe is what you need but never used it so I don't know how to use it.